# Troubleshoot Grunt concat and Uglify in Sails pipeline

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm working on a Sails.js app using angular 1.5x for front end. Recently I began working with textAngular, which works good in development, however, for some reason running in production, which (I believe to be the issue) runs grunt concat and uglify, therefore minimizing all js, I get a js error regarding injecting into my angular module/app. If I remove all references to textAngular it will concat/uglify and run fine in production. I want to use textAngular, and don't believe it is an issue with those scripts per say. How should I go about troubleshooting this issue? Are there any concat or uglify options that might help me pinpoint or resolve the issue?

ADDITIONAL INFO:
The angular code for injecting textAngular:

```
    var sangularApp =  angular.module('sangularApp', ['datatables', 'textAngular']).
    config(function($provide) { // provider-injector
      $provide.decorator('taOptions', ['$delegate', function(taOptions) { // $delegate is the taOptions we are decorating
        taOptions.toolbar = [
            ['pre', 'bold', 'italics', 'underline', 'strikeThrough','ol','insertLink', 'insertImage','html']
        ];
        return taOptions;
      }]);
    });
```

Here is the error I get (when I run in production and the files are minified:

```
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=sangularApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Da%0Ad%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A1797%0APa%2Fo.%24injector%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A20234%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A18987%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A19221%0Ak%2F%3C.invoke%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A19311%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A18448%0Aj%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A18580%0Af%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A2243%0Aj%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A18357%0APa%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A20389%0A_%2Fg%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A9026%0A_%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A9329%0A%24%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A10%3A8641%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A14%3A26564%0Afa.Callbacks%2Fj%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A2%3A7154%0Afa.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A2%3A7927%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A2%3A9741%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fcutupcode.com%2Fmin%2Fproduction.min.js%3A1%3A1606%0A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult question to respond to without some debugging information or console errors.

From what you've mentioned my suggestion would be to look back over your scripts and make sure that the additional library for textAngular has been included and that the injection of the library into your module is done correctly.

Minification and concatenation typically don't cause any issues for me when the library works fine without those tools applied.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I added code for how I do the injection, and the error I get, very odd I know, but the error only happens if I run in production, and although I'm not positive, I suspect the minification, per the error pointing to the minified file.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that somehow the order of files is different in concat and in development, I'm going to step through that, and try to manually order them instead of using named folders (a, b, c) which is what I am doing now, in development that properly orders them but perhaps not concat.

Comment: does minifying an already minified file cause issues? manually specifying the order didn't fix anything.

Comment: Minifying an already minified file should definitely not cause any issues.

Comment: got a hunch its related to this: http://www.sitepoint.com/5-minutes-to-min-safe-angular-code-with-grunt/

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't familiar with that myself! Thanks for the info.